# auto-correlation for multivariate data?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, stationarity

I know how auto-correlation for a univariate time series and how to plot ACF and how to interpret it

But what is the multivariate equivalent form of it?

Comment: Cross correlation? R function `ccf`.

Comment: Not the cross correlation, but rather how much X_{t} and X_{t-h} are correlated if X_{t} is a vector.

Comment: Right, cross-correlation is just bivariate...

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Covariance and correlation in multivariate random variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/216203).